# Need help with this phasor transformation

Tags: complex-numbers, transformation

I am reading a paper about making a phasor model of an inductor. For this they use phasor transformations.

The voltage over an inductor is calculated by $$v = L  \frac{di}{dt}$$ The current and voltage are in the paper defined as $$i(t) = \Re\left[\bar i(t) e^{j\int \omega_s dt}\right] $$ 
$$v(t) = \Re\left[\bar v(t) e^{j\int \omega_s dt}\right] $$

So now you basically fill the current and voltage in the first formula and in the paper they get the following result:
$$ \bar v(t) =L \frac{d}{dt}\bar i(t) +jL\bar i(t)\omega_s(t) $$

Now i tried to do this myself but I don't get to the same answer as they do in the paper. This is what I did:
$$\bar v(t) *\cos \left( \int\omega_s(t)dt\right) = L\frac{d\bar i(t)\cos(\int \omega_sdt)}{dt} $$
$$ \bar v(t) *\cos \left( \int\omega_s(t)dt\right)= L\left(\frac{d\bar i(t)}{dt}\cos(\int\omega_sdt)-\bar i(t)\omega_s(t)\sin(\int\omega_s(t)dt\right)$$
$$\bar v(t) = L\frac{d}{dt}\bar i(t)-\frac{\sin(\int\omega_s(t)dt)}{\cos(\int\omega_s(t)dt)}L\bar i(t)\omega_s(t) $$
$$\bar v(t) = L\frac{d}{dt}\bar i(t)-\tan(\int\omega_s(t)dt)L\bar i(t)\omega_s(t) $$
This is the point where I don't know how to go on. I have never really seen a tangent being equal to the complex number $j$. I think i am almost there but can anyone send me in the right direction on the last step?

Edit: $\omega_s$ is the instantanious frequency which is defined as $$\omega_s(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt} $$

Comment: Using phasors you are discarding the transitory response. With phasors the answer is a particular/permanent response to the process.

Comment: $\bar v(t)$ and $\bar i(t)$ are complex. You cannot bring them out of the $Re$ operator. @Cesareo These are istantaneous phasors, not "traditional" phasors, that is complex functions of the time.

Comment: @trying ok so basically what I did is not allowed. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a typo in your answer.  I suspect that the proper result is
$$\bar v\left( t \right) = L\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\,\bar i\left( t \right)} \right) + jL\,\bar i\left( t \right){\omega _s}\left( t \right)$$
To see this, in addition to the real parts of the phasors, we may assume that their imaginary parts (and thus the total complex sums) also fulfill the constitutive relationship.  Then
$$\bar v\left( t \right){e^{j\int {{\omega _s}dt} }} = L\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\bar i\left( t \right){e^{j\int {{\omega _s}dt} }}} \right)$$
or
$$\bar v\left( t \right) = L\frac{d}{{dt}}\left( {\bar i\left( t \right){e^{j\int {{\omega _s}dt} }}} \right){e^{ - j\int {{\omega _s}dt} }}$$
Expanding the derivative then leads to the modified result.

Comment: The answer you suspect is indeed the one i am looking for. I did what you you said and indeed I get to the answer. I only don't understand why we use the full v and i and not just the real part.

Comment: I think we can agree that the imaginary part may be defined as we desire (since we are ultimately interested in only the real part).  Lacking any explicit definition to the contrary, letting the imaginary parts fulfill the constitutive relation is both obvious and symbolically easy - probably so obvious that it is probably not even mentioned in the paper.  It is certainly the way we do it in traditional (time independent) phasor analysis.  Complex v/i is (V(w)/I(w))*exp(jwt), and substituting the complex forms (assuming the imaginary parts work correctly), gives the standard V(w)=jwL*I(w).

Comment: This is still a bit vague for me. I always learned that you can write this phasor in a cosine and a sine, which are the real and imaginary part respectively. Does this not apply to this case because it are instantaneous phasors?

Comment: I think you are missing the point I was trying to make - it applies in exactly same way, but we ALWAYS assume the whole complex phasor version fulfills the differential equations (we define it that way) whether we are working in either traditional or instantaneous phasors.  That is why we can use the full v and i and not just the real part.

Answer (score 1):

Now you know how to get to the result but you have still some doubts: "why can't I make use of the real part only?" - said you.

Your difficulties arise from the fact that what you reported from the paper is not fully clear or correct.
Let me just start by changing expression like this:
$$x(t) = \Re\left[\bar x(t) e^{j\int{\omega_sdt}}\right]$$
in
$$x(t)=\Re\left[\bar x(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}\right]$$ 
where $\phi_s(t) = \int_{t_0}^t\omega_s(\tau)d\tau+\phi_s(t_0)$ in order to have a less cluttered notation (and more importantly in order to take into consideration $\phi_s(t_0)$ even though no effect are apparent by forgetting it)

If one defines a phasor associated to a real function $x(t)$ with this expression:
$$x(t)=\Re\left[\bar x(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}\right]$$ then two possible
interpretations are usual: one where $\bar x(t)$ a real positive function
(the magnitude of $x(t)$) and another where $\bar x(t)$ a complex function (we are assuming $\phi_s(t)$ is a real function).

**First interpretation: $\bar x(t)$ positive real function**

This is the interpretation you gave, as I can guess.
There are infinite many ways to choose a phasor given the real function, because you have two real coordinates $\bar x(t)$ and $\phi_s(t)$ for a single real quantity $x(t)$, that is, the phasor has an imaginary part. Here it may be interesting to understand what happens to the model when such an imaginary part is chosen to be not identically zero. In the problem at hand you have two real functions $i(t)$ and $v(t)$ of which you want to get the corresponding phasors. You know the model (what relation exists between the real functions) $v = L\frac{di}{dt}$ and you want an extended model, that is, you want to know how you can accomodate such relation for it to hold between the corresponding phasors.
The arbitrariness in choosing $\bar x(t)$ and $\phi_s(t)$ and then ultimately in choosing the imaginary part is allowed just for one of those phasors, the other is constrained by what we want the extended model to possess as a property.

So in choosing those phasors you must take full generality, in order to be able to set the constraint needed to guarantee extended model property:
$$i(t) = \Re\left[\bar i(t) e^{j\phi_s^i(t)}\right]$$
and
$$v(t) = \Re\left[\bar v(t) e^{j\phi_s^v(t)}\right]$$

Please note that $\phi_s^i(t)$ and $\phi_s^v(t)$ are not equal in general, you are not entitled to choose them arbitrarily equal (that would make impossible choosing the right property for the extended model).

Making the substitution in the original model equation, we have:
$$\bar v(t)\cos\phi_s^v(t) = L \frac{d}{dt}\left(\bar i(t)\cos\phi_s^i(t)\right)$$
and expanding the right-hand side:
$$\bar v(t)\cos\phi_s^v(t) = L \frac{d\bar i}{dt}\cos\phi_s^i(t) -\omega_s^i(t) L\bar i(t)\sin\phi_s^i(t) \tag{a}$$
We see that the real part of the voltage phasor is a (real) linear combination of the imaginary part of the current phasor and the real part of a new phasor $\frac{d\bar i}{dt}e^{j\phi_s^i(t)}$.

A tacit desideratum in a phasor model is that it must remain a linear model if the original model is so. 
The original model says that $\bar v(t)$ is proportional (through a real constant) to the first temporal derivative of $\bar i(t)$.
So the linearity is a constraint that must purposely be imposed, otherwise no benefit in using phasor model would be attained, that is the relation between $\bar v(t)$ and the temporal derivatives of $\bar i(t)$ must be linear as is that between $v(t)$ and $i(t)$.

Anyway, the linearity in the original (real) model and that in the extended (complex) model are *different* linearities: they are real linearity and complex linearity, respectively.

So we want that $\bar v(t) = \mathcal{L}(t) \frac{d\bar i}{dt} + \mathcal{R}(t) \bar i(t)$, where $\mathcal{L}(t)=\mathcal{l}_{11}(t)+j\mathcal{l}_{12}(t)$ and $\mathcal{R}(t)=\mathcal{r}_{11}(t) + j \mathcal{r}_{12}(t)$ are complex quantities.
Decomplexifying we clearly see what's the difference between real and complex linearity:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\bar v(t)\cos\phi_s^v(t) \\
\bar v(t)\sin\phi_s^v(t) 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}\mathcal{l}_{11} & \mathcal{l}_{12} \\
-\mathcal{l}_{12} & \mathcal{l}_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{d\bar i}{dt}\cos\phi_s^i(t) \\
\frac{d\bar i}{dt}\sin\phi_s^i(t) 
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{-}\mathcal{r}_{11} & \mathcal{r}_{12} \\
-\mathcal{r}_{12} & \mathcal{r}_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\bar i(t)\cos\phi_s^i(t) \\
\bar i(t)\sin\phi_s^i(t) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

that is, the matrices are limited to be orthogonal, $\mathcal{l}_{21}=-\mathcal{l}_{12}$ and $\mathcal{l}_{22}=\mathcal{l}_{11}$ and $\mathcal{r}_{21}=-\mathcal{r}_{12}$ and $\mathcal{r}_{22}=\mathcal{r}_{11}$.

Now we know the first row of the matrices of the decomplexification of $\mathcal{L}(t)$ and $\mathcal{R}(t)$: from $(a)$ you see that $\mathcal{l}_{11}(t) = L$, $\mathcal{l}_{12}(t) = 0$, $\mathcal{r}_{11}(t) = 0$, and $\mathcal{r}_{12}(t) = -\omega_s(t)L$.

It follows that the imaginary part of the voltage phasor is determined:

$$\bar v(t)\sin\phi_s^v(t) = L \frac{d\bar i}{dt}\sin\phi_s^i(t) +\omega_s^i(t) L\bar i(t)\cos\phi_s^i(t) \tag{b}$$

That was the reason why you could not put $\phi_s^v(t)=\phi_s^i(t)$, that is, that degree of freedom was needed to impose the highly desired (complex) linearity of the model.

Now, of course, you can complexify back (summing $(a)$ to $j$ times $(b)$) and observing that 
$$\bar v(t)\cos\phi_s^v(t) = \bar v(t)\cos\phi_s^i(t)\cos\theta_s(t)-\bar v(t)\sin\phi_s^i(t)\sin\theta_s(t)$$
and 
$$\bar v(t)\sin\phi_s^v(t) = \bar v(t)\sin\phi_s^i(t)\cos\theta_s(t)+\bar v(t)\cos\phi_s^i(t)\sin\theta_s(t)$$
where $\theta_s(t) = \phi_s^v(t)-\phi_s^i(t)$,
thus getting:
$$\bar v(t) e^{j\theta_s(t)}= L \frac{d\bar i}{dt} +j\omega_s^i(t) L\bar i(t)$$

**Second interpretation: $\bar x(t)$ complex function**

This is the intepretation taken by the Authors in the paper.
Let's think of a real function $x(t)$ as one component of a two-component real function (or equivalently as the real part of a complex-valued function) in a given coordinate system. Let's conventionally call this coordinate system *stationary*. Let's call this complex-valued function *phasor in the stationary coordinate system*. So we have that $$x(t) = \Re[\bar x_s(t)]$$
Now we want to examine what changes relations involving such phasors undergo when a coordinate system transformation occurs. But we do not want to take into consideration all the possible coordinate system transformations: we are interested only in real plane rotation. Such transformations are multiplicatively represented by all and only all orthogonal matrices of determinant $1$, or in the complex model, by all and only all complex numbers of magnitude $1$.
So this is the coordinate system transformation: $$\bar x_s(t) = \bar x(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}$$ where $\phi_s(t)$ gives the angular position of the new (conventionally called *moving*) coordinate system w.r.t. the stationary one.

Now we know a linear differential relation between $v(t)$ and $i(t)$ two temporal real functions, or we can now say between the real part of two phasors in the stationary coordinate system. We want to know how the analytical expression of such a relation changes after a rotational coordinate system transformation. But before doing this we need first to extend the relation to phasors that entails to extend the real linear differential operator to complex-valued functions. We extend by linearity, that is we want that the extended differential is complex linear. So in the stationary coordinate system the relation between the phasors must be:
$$\bar v_s(t) = \mathcal{L_s}(t)\frac{d\bar i_s(t)}{dt}+\mathcal{R_s}(t)\bar i_s(t)$$where $\mathcal{L_s}(t)$ and $\mathcal{R_s}(t)$ are in general complex function, but in this case are real constants, $\mathcal{L_s}(t) = L$ and $\mathcal{R_s}(t) = 0$ .

Being the coordinate system transformations for the phasors be given by:

$$\bar v_s(t) = \bar v(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}$$
$$\bar i_s(t) = \bar i(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}$$

we can have the analytical representation of the complex linear differential operator in the moving coordinate system by substitution:

$$\bar v(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)} = \mathcal{L_s}(t)\frac{d}{dt}\left(\bar i(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}\right)+\mathcal{R_s}(t)\bar i(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}$$

that expands to:

$$\bar v(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)} = \mathcal{L_s}(t)\frac{d\bar i}{dt}e^{j\phi_s(t)}+\left(\mathcal{R_s}(t)+j\omega_s(t)\mathcal{L_s}(t)\right)\bar i(t)e^{j\phi_s(t)}$$
where $\omega_s(t)=\frac{d\phi_s(t)}{dt}$ is the angular speed of the moving coordinate system w.r.t. the stationary one.

In the end we have:
$$\bar v(t) = \mathcal{L}(t)\frac{d\bar i}{dt}+\mathcal{R}(t)\bar i(t)$$
where
$$\mathcal{L}(t) = \mathcal{L_s}(t)$$
$$\mathcal{R}(t) = \mathcal{R_s}(t)+j\omega_s(t)\mathcal{L_s}(t)$$

that for our particular case yields:

$$\bar v(t) = L\frac{d\bar i}{dt}+j\omega_s(t)L\bar i(t)$$
**Conclusions**

The two different interpretations gives two different results of course. So one must know what the symbols are, as is always the case.

More importantly, in both cases one can choose the imaginary part of at least one phasor arbitrarily when one has to treat only one real function.
 There are circumstances (electrical machine theory) where both the real and the imaginary parts of the stationary phasor have physical meaning: in such a case phasor models find its best use.